# 78 dodge sportsman

Tags: starting, dodge, sportsman

We have a 78 dodge sportsman. It started last week and was moved from the driveway to the side yard. Now it won't start. Doesn't make any clicking sounds at all even when we tried to jumpstart it. The dash lights don't even come on

Comment: Have you checked the battery? If not do so - you may have left a light on... Try charging it for 24 hours then see.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!